# Is it possible to detect different types of trapezoids

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I want to scan a sudoku and solve it with an algorithm. I do not only want to to predict if it is a sudoku puzzle and extract the numbers when I'm perfectly above it (so 0 degree rotation towards me, phone is horizontally above sudoku. And 0 degree rotation around the puzzle). I also want to do this if the phone is shifted towards the user (up to 45 degrees) and can be rotated around to object (up to 45 degrees in both directions). Is it possible to detect this? Because I have so many combinations I need to care of. I don't want a concrete solution, I'm just curios if this is implementable. Also, if I was inaccurate with something let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do it.

Generally sudoku puzzle has a thick outer border. You can detect it pretty easy (for example on binary version of your input snap but there are many options). If outer border is not thicker than inner ones you may determine which of detected borders is outer and closer to square shape.

When you have puzzle's border than you need to remove its **skewness and rotation** (and it's common preprocessing step for CV apps detecting various labels, plates and other planar objects) convenient way is to use [perspective transformation](https://huningxin.github.io/opencv_docs/d5/dfc/warpPerspective_demo_8cpp-example.html#a26).

*Preference one one or another detection method should be based on input images and possible variance in them. Detecting black-white square-shaped sudoku which is 95% of input snapshot is not same as detecting multiple sudokus (small relative to input snapshot) pinned to black and white brick wall.*